# How to change Datatypes of records inserting into Cassandra using Foreach Spark Structure streaming

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to Insert the Deserialized Kafka records to Data Stax Cassandra using Spark Structure Streaming using Foreach Sink.

For example, my deserialized Data frame data like all are in string format.

```
id   name    date
100 'test' sysdate
```

Using foreach Sink I created a class and trying to insert the records as below by converting it.

```
session.execute(
  s"""insert into ${cassandraDriver.namespace}.${cassandraDriver.brand_dub_sink} (id,name,date)
  values  ('${row.getAs[Long](0)}','${rowstring(1)}','${rowstring(2)}')"""))
  }
)
```

I exactly followed this project
https://github.com/epishova/Structured-Streaming-Cassandra-Sink/blob/master/src/main/scala/cassandra_sink.scala

when inserting into Cassandra table converting the string "id" column datatype to Long as mentioned above, It is not converting. And throwing error

> "Invalid STRING constant (100) for "id" of type bigint"

CASSANDRA TABLE;-

```
create table test(
id bigint,
name text,
date timestamp)
```

Any suggestions to convert the string datatype to Long inside "def Process".

It will be great any alternative suggestion also.Thanks

This is the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

class CassandraSinkForeach() extends ForeachWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] {
  // This class implements the interface ForeachWriter, which has methods that get called 
  // whenever there is a sequence of rows generated as output

  var cassandraDriver: CassandraDriver = null;
  def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
    // open connection
    println(s"Open connection")
    true
  }

  def process(record: org.apache.spark.sql.Row) = {
    println(s"Process new $record")
    if (cassandraDriver == null) {
      cassandraDriver = new CassandraDriver();
    }
    cassandraDriver.connector.withSessionDo(session =>
      session.execute(s"""
       insert into ${cassandraDriver.namespace}.${cassandraDriver.foreachTableSink} (fx_marker, timestamp_ms, timestamp_dt)
       values('${record.getLong(0)}', '${record(1)}', '${record(2)}')""")
    )
  }

  def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
    // close the connection
    println(s"Close connection")
  }
}

class SparkSessionBuilder extends Serializable {
  // Build a spark session. Class is made serializable so to get access to SparkSession in a driver and executors. 
  // Note here the usage of @transient lazy val 
  def buildSparkSession: SparkSession = {
    @transient lazy val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("Structured Streaming from Kafka to Cassandra")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "ec2-52-23-103-178.compute-1.amazonaws.com")
    .set("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")

    @transient lazy val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config(conf)
    .getOrCreate()

    spark
  }
}

class CassandraDriver extends SparkSessionBuilder {
  // This object will be used in CassandraSinkForeach to connect to Cassandra DB from an executor.
  // It extends SparkSessionBuilder so to use the same SparkSession on each node.
  val spark = buildSparkSession

  import spark.implicits._

  val connector = CassandraConnector(spark.sparkContext.getConf)

  // Define Cassandra's table which will be used as a sink
  /* For this app I used the following table:
       CREATE TABLE fx.spark_struct_stream_sink (
       id Bigint,
       name text,
       timestamp_dt date,
       primary key (id));
  */
  val namespace = "fx"
  val foreachTableSink = "spark_struct_stream_sink"
}

object KafkaToCassandra extends SparkSessionBuilder {
  // Main body of the app. It also extends SparkSessionBuilder.
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = buildSparkSession

    import spark.implicits._

    // Define location of Kafka brokers:
    val broker = "ec2-18-209-75-68.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9092,ec2-18-205-142-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9092,ec2-50-17-32-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9092"

    /*Here is an example massage which I get from a Kafka stream. It contains multiple jsons separated by \n 
    {"100": "test1", "01-mar-2018"}
    {"101": "test2", "02-mar-2018"}  */
    val dfraw = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", broker)
    .option("subscribe", "currency_exchange")
    .load()

    val schema = StructType(
      Seq(
        StructField("id", StringType, false),
        StructField("name", StringType, false),
StructField("date", StringType, false)

      )
    )

    val df = dfraw
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String]
    .flatMap(_.split("\n"))

    val jsons = df.select(from_json($"value", schema) as "data").select("data.*")


    val sink = jsons
    .writeStream
    .queryName("KafkaToCassandraForeach")
    .outputMode("update")
    .foreach(new CassandraSinkForeach())
    .start()

    sink.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

My modified code;-

```
def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
    // open connection
    println(s"in my Open connection")
    val cassandraDriver = new CassandraDriver();
    true
  }


  def process(record: Row) = {


    val optype = record(0)

    if (cassandraDriver == null) {
      val  cassandraDriver = new CassandraDriver();
    }

  if (optype == "I" || optype == "U") {

        println(s"Process insert or Update Idempotent new $record")

        cassandraDriver.connector.withSessionDo(session =>{
          val prepare_rating_brand = session.prepare(s"""insert into ${cassandraDriver.namespace}.${cassandraDriver.brand_dub_sink} (table_name,op_type,op_ts,current_ts,pos,brand_id,brand_name,brand_creation_dt,brand_modification_dt,create_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""")

          session.execute(prepare_rating_brand.bind(record.getAs[String](0),record.getAs[String](1),record.getAs[String](2),record.getAs[String](3),record.getAs[String](4),record.getAs[BigInt](5),record.getAs[String](6),record.getAs[String](7),record.getAs[String](8),record.getAs[String](9))
          )

        })
      }  else if (optype == "D") {

        println(s"Process delete new $record")
        cassandraDriver.connector.withSessionDo(session =>
          session.execute(s"""DELETE FROM ${cassandraDriver.namespace}.${cassandraDriver.brand_dub_sink} WHERE brand_id = ${record.getAs[Long](5)}"""))

      } else if (optype == "T") {
        println(s"Process Truncate new $record")
        cassandraDriver.connector.withSessionDo(session =>
          session.execute(s"""Truncate table  ${cassandraDriver.namespace}.${cassandraDriver.plan_rating_archive_dub_sink}"""))

      }
    }

  def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
    // close the connection
    println(s"Close connection")
  }


}
```

Comment: If you're using Spark 2.4.x, then you can use the `foreachBatch` instead - it's much simpler than `foreach`. Here is an example: https://github.com/alexott/spark-cassandra-oss-demos/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/streaming/StructuredStreamingForEachBatch.scala#L59

Comment: Thanks, @Alex Ott. I am using Spark 2.2 with datastax 6.0.

Comment: if you're using DataStax distribution, you can simply use `writeStream` instead, withouth this processor: https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/streaming/StructuredStreamingDSE.scala#L53 - in another file in same folder, there is an example for Kafka

Comment: ok, @AlexOtt, Consider this scenario I am having 10 queries writing in datastax, One query got terminated in spark. I am having streaming query manager, Checkpoint and exception handling everything. Do you guide me on how to restart that particular query without affecting the session? since I already have queryawaittermination() handled.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not understand it fully. Query is usually retried automatically if possible: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/retries/ but you may need to specifically mark it as idempotent. But as I mentioned, if you're on DataStax Enterprise - you don't need to write all this code yourself - you just need to use `writeStream` - then DSE connector will handle everything automatically

Comment: I agree with @Alex Ott. But I have to insert based on the column op type value  "I" or "U" or "D". [if "I" I have to insert "U" then update the "D" delete the row].  It is possible to handle this scenario, Alex?

Comment: Also how to convert the record(0) object value to Cassandra double format when inserting into Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you specify value for `id` field as `'${row.getAs[Long](0)}'` - you've added the single quotes around it, so it's treated as string, not as a `long`/`bigint` - just remove single quotes around this value: `${row.getAs[Long](0)}`...

Also, for performance reasons it's better to move instantiation of the cassandra driver into `open` method, and use the prepared statements, something like this:

```scala
  var cassandraDriver: CassandraDriver = null;
  var preparedStatement: PreparedStatement = null;
  def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
    // open connection
    println(s"Open connection")
    cassandraDriver = new CassandraDriver();
    preparedStatement = cassandraDriver.connector.withSessionDo(session =>
      session.prepare(s"""
       insert into ${cassandraDriver.namespace}.${cassandraDriver.foreachTableSink} 
      (fx_marker, timestamp_ms, timestamp_dt) values(?, ?, ?)""")
    true
  }

  def process(record: org.apache.spark.sql.Row) = {
    println(s"Process new $record")
    cassandraDriver.connector.withSessionDo(session =>
      session.execute(preparedStatement.bind(${record.getLong(0)}, 
           ${record(1)}, ${record(2)}))
    )
  }
```

it will be more performant, and you'll need not to perform quoting of the values yourself.

Comment: Hi Alex,   one more doubt. I am receiving all data from golden gate to Kafka with one more parameter op_type = I(Insert) or U(Update). So I will consume data [insert or update]  based on that I have to insert in Cassandra.so I have to handle Prepared statements inside [def Process]. Is this possible

Comment: so just prepare 2 different queries, and select them depending on the flag.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ott.  https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-421?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel. I read it from Data stax. So foreach internally havng preparing statements?

Comment: Ah, yes - forgot about it... You can mark this field as `@transient` - see https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/serialization-issues-part-2/read

Comment: Hi Alex, One more doubt, When I try to update on the column it is having String like "Bravo Daytime-D (M-F 8 AM-3 PM)" and I am getting an error like                                             com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 60:24 no viable alternative at input 'Bravo' (... =63904,
    sales_unit_name = ''[Bravo]...)       How to use escape characters dynamically. ?  @Alex Ott

Comment: when you use prepared statements you don't need to escape data yourself - this is one of the big advantages in addition to lower load on the nodes. See documentation for details: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/statements/prepared/

Comment: oh ok, @Alex Ott. But I have to insert based on the op_type column value(I or D or U). So in def open, I am not able to prepare https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56883558/revisions. Since I m new to Cassandra pls advice me.

Comment: Just create N prepared statements - different for each op types. Another possibility is to use SimoleStatement, but it’s not so effective as prepared statements

Comment: ok, @Alex Ott. I attempted the code u have shared above. But when I apply it in the process in session. execute it is showing "Cannot resolve overloaded method 'execute'". Any suggestions

Comment: I still see the old code with single quotes around first number - just remove them

Comment: thanks for your guidance. I tried like above modified code and working fine. But I can convert the data type to String or BigInt. Double is not working and showing some implicit conversion error!!! any idea on that.?. Once again I am thanking you. Also, advice me about my strategy is it good?

Comment: You should prepare each statement only once - either in `open`, or on demand. By using prepare for every record you're really decreasing performance of your system - because `prepare` requires an additional round trip to server. You can look into this code as an example of preparing statements on demand: https://github.com/alexott/spark-cassandra-oss-demos/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/streaming/StructuredStreaming.scala